# Django GraphQL subscription not returning any data

Tags: django, graphql, subscription, graphene-django

I'm using Graphene, Django and [graphene-subscriptions](https://github.com/jaydenwindle/graphene-subscriptions) to define a GraphQL Subscription. I'm trying to receive updates whenever a new `Book` with a specific `Author` is created. I've followed the getting started guide, and I'm trying to use the following code:

```py
class SubscriptionBook(graphene.ObjectType):
    NewBooks = graphene.Field(BookType, Author = graphene.String(required=True))

    def resolve_NewBooks(root, info, Author):

        return root.filter( 
            lambda event:
                event.operation == CREATED  and
                isinstance(event.instance, Book) and
                event.instance.AuthorID == Author
        ).map(lambda event: event.instance)
```

But it doesn't seem to work. It appears that this line is failing:

```py
event.instance.AuthorID == Author
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the common problems I've run into when defining subscriptions like this is having a type mismatch when filtering by `id`.

Because `Author` is a string, if `event.instance.AuthorID` is a Django primary key (an `int` value), then

```py
event.instance.AuthorID == Author
```

will return `False`.

You can fix this by type-casting the `Author` value to an `int` like so:

```py
event.instance.AuthorID == int(Author)
```